# Is there a method or function to get previous executing task's name in jBPM 6.2?

Tags: java, jbpm

I'm thinking of using I/O mapping to pass the previous task's name (`workItem.getName()`) to the current task.

I was wondering whether there exists an alternative method or function that jBPM 6.2 has that allows me to get the previous task's name?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "previous task" - previous task in a process? Because there could be many...

Comment: Yes. I would like to retrieve previous tasks in a process. Is there a way to get all of them?